# Writing a formated binary file from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, binaryfiles

I've seen some ways to read a formatted binary file in Python to Pandas,
namely, I'm using this code that read using NumPy fromfile formatted with a structure given using dtype.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input_file_name = 'test.hst'

input_file = open(input_file_name, 'rb')
header = input_file.read(96)

dt_header = np.dtype([('version', 'i4'),
                      ('copyright', 'S64'),
                      ('symbol', 'S12'),
                      ('period', 'i4'),
                      ('digits', 'i4'),
                      ('timesign', 'i4'),
                      ('last_sync', 'i4')])

header = np.fromstring(header, dt_header)

dt_records = np.dtype([('ctm', 'i4'),
                       ('open', 'f8'),
                       ('low', 'f8'),
                       ('high', 'f8'),
                       ('close', 'f8'),
                       ('volume', 'f8')])
records = np.fromfile(input_file, dt_records)

input_file.close()

df_records = pd.DataFrame(records)
# Now, do some changes in the individual values of df_records
# and then write it back to a binary file
```

Now, my issue is on how to write this back to a new file. I can't find any function in NumPy (neither in Pandas) that allows me to specify exactly the bytes to use in each field to write.

Comment: Whats wrong with using the `records.tofile` method. It writes the data in the same format as it is stored in memory.

Answer (score 9):

Pandas now offers [a wide variety of formats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) that are more stable than tofile(). tofile() is best for quick file storage where you do not expect the file to be used on a different machine where the data may have a different endianness (big-/little-endian).

```
Format Type Data Description     Reader         Writer
text        CSV                  read_csv       to_csv
text        JSON                 read_json      to_json
text        HTML                 read_html      to_html
text        Local clipboard      read_clipboard to_clipboard
binary      MS Excel             read_excel     to_excel
binary      HDF5 Format          read_hdf       to_hdf
binary      Feather Format       read_feather   to_feather
binary      Parquet Format       read_parquet   to_parquet
binary      Msgpack              read_msgpack   to_msgpack
binary      Stata                read_stata     to_stata
binary      SAS                  read_sas    
binary      Python Pickle Format read_pickle    to_pickle
SQL         SQL                  read_sql       to_sql
SQL         Google Big Query     read_gbq       to_gbq
```

For small to medium sized files, I prefer CSV, as properly-formatted CSV can store arbitrary string data, is human readable, and is as dirt-simple as any format can be while achieving the previous two goals.

At one time, I used HDF5, but if I were on Amazon, I would consider using parquet.

Example of using [to_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html):

```
df.to_hdf('tmp.hdf','df', mode='w')
df2 = pd.read_hdf('tmp.hdf','df')
```

I no longer favor the HDF5 format. It has serious risks for long-term archival since it is [fairly complex](https://cyrille.rossant.net/moving-away-hdf5/). It has a 150 page specification, and only one 300,000 line C implementation.

In contrast, as long as you are working exclusively in Python, the [pickle format claims long term stability](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> The pickle serialization format is guaranteed to be backwards
> compatible across Python releases provided a compatible pickle
> protocol is chosen and pickling and unpickling code deals with Python
> 2 to Python 3 type differences if your data is crossing that unique
> breaking change language boundary.

However, pickles allow arbitrary code execution so care should be exercised with pickles of unknown origin.

Comment: I've added a question that surveys formats for Python data science in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583264/what-are-the-standard-stable-file-formats-used-in-python-for-data-science

Answer (score 7):

It isn't clear to me if the `DataFrame` is a view or a copy, but assuming it is a copy, you can use the [`to_records` method of the `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html).

This gives you back a record array that you can then put to disk using `tofile`.

e.g.

```
df_records = pd.DataFrame(records)
# do some stuff
new_recarray = df_records.to_records()
new_recarray.tofile("myfile.npy")
```

The data will reside in memory as packed bytes with the format described by the recarray dtype.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't aware that this way it would write a binary file using the same data structure as the numpy array.

I did had to do some extra, since the data was changed from the operations I did in the Pandas Dataframe. But after putting it all back in the needed types, it did work correctly.