# What are the standard, stable file formats used in Python for Data Science?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I often want to quickly save some Python data, but I would also like to save it in a stable file format in case the date lingers for a long time.  And so I have the question, how can I save my data?

In data science, there are three kinds of data I want to store -- arbitrary Python objects, numpy arrays, and Pandas dataframes. -- what are the stable ways of storing these?

Comment: @duhaime: Answering your own question is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @duhaime This question is not subjective.  I review only guaranteed-stable file formats included in standard libraries.  Also, asking and answering a question in the same minute [is encouraged and explicitly enabled by the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Also, the question is not off-topic.  It pertains directly to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Arbitrary Python data and code** can be stored in the **`.pkl` pickle format**.  While pickle files **have security concerns** because loading them can execute arbitrary code, if you can trust the source of a pickle file, it is a stable format.

[The Python standard library's pickle page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> The pickle serialization format is guaranteed to be backwards compatible across Python releases provided a compatible pickle protocol is chosen and pickling and unpickling code deals with Python 2 to Python 3 type differences if your data is crossing that unique breaking change language boundary.

**Most python data** can also be stored in the [json format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).  I haven't used this format much myself, but [dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg) recommends it.   Like the CSV and tab-delimited format I recommend for Pandas, the json format is a plain-text format that is very stable.

**Numpy arrays** can be [stored](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) in the [`.npy` or `.npz` numpy formats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format).  The npy format is a very simple format that stores a single numpy array.  I imagine it would be easy to read this format in any language.  The npz format allows the storing of multiple arrays in the same file.  [Adapted from the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html),

```
x = np.arange(10)
np.save('example.npy',x)
y = np.load('example.npy')
```

If the integrity of the file being loaded is not guaranteed, be sure to use `allow_pickle=False` to avoid arbitrary code execution.

**Pandas dataframes** can be stored in a variety of formats.  As [I wrote in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51106891/1048186), Pandas offers [a wide variety of formats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html).  For small datasets, I find plaintext file formats such as CSV and tab-delimited to work well for most purposes.  These formats are readable in a wide variety of languages and I have had no issues in working in a bilingual R and Python environment where both environments read from these files.

```
Format Type Data Description     Reader         Writer
text        CSV                  read_csv       to_csv
text        JSON                 read_json      to_json
text        HTML                 read_html      to_html
text        Local clipboard      read_clipboard to_clipboard
binary      MS Excel             read_excel     to_excel
binary      HDF5 Format          read_hdf       to_hdf
binary      Feather Format       read_feather   to_feather
binary      Parquet Format       read_parquet   to_parquet
binary      Msgpack              read_msgpack   to_msgpack
binary      Stata                read_stata     to_stata
binary      SAS                  read_sas    
binary      Python Pickle Format read_pickle    to_pickle
SQL         SQL                  read_sql       to_sql
SQL         Google Big Query     read_gbq       to_gbq
```

When writing csv and tab files from pandas, I often use the `index=False` option to avoid saving the index, which loads as an oddly-named column by default.

Comment: Great answer. Suggest you add the standard library JSON implementation as well.

Comment: @dawg Done. Thanks for a secure(er?) alternative to pickle when the file can't be trusted.